# How to get multiple SUM with one SQL query?

Tags: mysql, sql, select, group-by, sum

I am wondering how to fix this query.

```
SELECT
SUM(`month_using`) used,
SUM(`month_cash`) paycash,
SUM(`month_profit` CASE WHEN `id` <> 'system' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) profit
FROM `_using_month`
WHERE MONTH(`month_date`) = {month} AND YEAR(`month_date`) = {year}
```

Thanks

Comment: what is your problem?

Answer (score 1):

Use [**Group by**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/group-by-functions.html) clause to get multiple **SUM**:

For Example:

```
SELECT YEAR(month_date), MONTH(month_date), 
       SUM(month_using) used, SUM(month_cash) paycash, 
       SUM(month_profit CASE WHEN id <> 'system' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) profit
FROM _using_month
GROUP BY YEAR(month_date), MONTH(month_date)
```